# expand a list to list of lists by a variable length

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list

```
my_input_list = [22,33,56,1]
```

and from a variable target_len I want to make (exclusive, sorted) sublists of that length

```
target_len = 2
#my_output_list_not_sorted = [[22,33][22,56][22,1][33,56][33,1][56,1]]
my_output_list = [[22,33][22,56][1,22][33,56][1,33][1,56]]
```

or

```
target_len = 3
#my_output_list_not_sorted = [[[22,33,56][22,33,1][33,56,1]]
my_output_list = [[22,33,56][1,22,33][1,33,56]]
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

I'm OK to sort my_input_list first if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `itertools.combinations`

```
import itertools
my_input_list = [22,33,56,1]
target_len = 2
print([sorted(x) for x in itertools.combinations(my_input_list, target_len)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[22, 33], [22, 56], [1, 22], [33, 56], [1, 33], [1, 56]]
```

Comment: I think you want to print `[sorted(x) for x in itertools.combinations(my_input_list, 2)]`

Comment: @Bahrom. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah itertools.  Is there anything you can't do <3  Also I did google and search first, didn't find that question. Thank you.